# sed replace spaces in filename path from syslog event

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

i'm stumped on how to replace spaces *only* in the 'sproc=' filepath of this log event for parsing. I'm trying to use awk (using `awk -F" "`) to print out just the sproc= field, the user= field and a few others, but my results are inconsistent because some of the 'sproc=' fields have spaces in the filenames. Can anyone give some guidance on how to either remove spaces from the filename, but not the other spaces in the event message?

```
user=myuser sproc=C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe act=read_file fileId=F:\\afolder\\hifile filePath=\\Test1 Data\\Read this too.rtf somevar=somedata anothervar=moredata
```

example output:

```
myuser@myhost ~ $ awk -F" " '{print "the user is: " $1 "the sproc is: " $2 "somevar is: " $6 }' < sedme 
the user is: user=myuserthe sproc is: sproc=C:\\Program somevar is: fileId=F:\\afolder\\hifile
```

expected output:

```
the user is: user=myuserthe sproc is: sproc=C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe somevar is: somevar=somedata
```

Comment: post a few lines of sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is better done in perl if you've got it:

```
perl -ne 'while(/(^|\s+)(\w+)=(.*?)(?=($|\s+\w+=))/g){print "the $2 is: $3\n"}'
```

The key pattern is recognizing [spaces][keyword]=[value], rather than just space-separation.

I get the following on your data:

```
the user is: myuser
the sproc is: C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe
the act is: read_file
the fileId is: F:\\afolder\\hifile
the filePath is: \\Test1 Data\\Read this too.rtf
the somevar is: somedata
the anothervar is: moredata
```

Answer (score 1):

However you want to do whatever you want to do it included in this script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/[^[:space:]=]+=[^=]+/) ) {
        fld = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"",fld)
        f[++nf] = fld
        split(fld,a,/=/)
        n2v[a[1]] = a[2]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+length(fld))
    }

    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        print i, "<" f[i] ">"
    }

    print ""

    for (name in n2v) {
        value = n2v[name]
        print name, "= [" value "]"
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 <user=myuser>
2 <sproc=C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe>
3 <act=read_file>
4 <fileId=F:\\afolder\\hifile>
5 <filePath=\\Test1 Data\\Read this too.rtf>
6 <somevar=somedata>
7 <anothervar=moredata>

sproc = [C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe]
user = [myuser]
filePath = [\\Test1 Data\\Read this too.rtf]
anothervar = [moredata]
somevar = [somedata]
fileId = [F:\\afolder\\hifile]
act = [read_file]
```

just take your pick of how you want the fields stored and accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -oP` you can get `sproc=...` value:

```
grep -oP 'sproc=.+?(?= +\w+=)' file
sproc=C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe
```

Or if you want to get rid of `sproc=` as well:

```
grep -oP 'sproc=\K.+?(?= +\w+=)' file
C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a POSIX compliant grep line for this, but -o is really useful and probably should be added to the specifications.